# Python's nquad is incredibly slow for this integral of a smooth function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scientific-computing

I was hoping to use Python functionality as much as possible for a new project but I have run into a severe computational efficiency issue, I'm hoping it can be resolved so I don't have to start linking to C++ at this early stage.

I have the following code which is related to integration over two triangles that have a vertex in common and thus an integrand that may become singular.

This is kind of irrelevant however, the code below is 'regularized' so that there is no singular behavior and the integration is now taking place over the domain (0,1)^4. As the integrand is smooth I expected nquad to integrate this very efficiently, however it takes around 7 seconds on my machine in a Jupyter notebook (i7-8700K, 3.70GHz × 6, 32 GB RAM).

This seems incredibly slow for integration of a smooth function. I have only been using Python for 2 months so maybe my code is poorly written from a performance point of view?

Is there any way to speed up this integration or do I have to resort to C++ to get fast integration?

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA
from scipy.integrate import nquad
import time

##################################################
# Triangle vertices
##################################################
v_a_1 = np.array([[4,0,0]]).T
v_a_2 = np.array([[5,1,0]]).T
v_a_3 = np.array([[4,2,0]]).T

v_b_1 = np.array([[4,0,0]]).T
v_b_2 = np.array([[5,-1,0]]).T
v_b_3 = np.array([[4,-2,0]]).T

##################################################
# g_tau
##################################################
def g_tau():
    J_tau = v_a_2-v_a_1
    J_tau = np.append(J_tau, v_a_3-v_a_2,axis=1)
    G = np.dot(J_tau.T,J_tau)
    return np.sqrt(LA.det(G))

##################################################
# g_t
##################################################
def g_t():
    J_t = v_b_2-v_b_1
    J_t = np.append(J_t, v_b_3-v_b_2,axis=1)
    G = np.dot(J_t.T,J_t)
    return np.sqrt(LA.det(G))

##################################################
# chi_tau
##################################################
def chi_tau(x):
    return v_a_1 + (v_a_2-v_a_1)*x[0] + (v_a_3-v_a_2)*x[1]

##################################################
# chi_t
##################################################
def chi_t(y):
    return v_b_1 + (v_b_2-v_b_1)*y[0] + (v_b_3-v_b_2)*y[1]

##################################################
# k_
##################################################
def k_(x,y):
    return LA.norm(x+y)

##################################################
# k
##################################################
def k(x,y):
    return k_(chi_tau(x),chi_t(y))*g_tau()*g_t()

##################################################
# func
##################################################
def func(z, y, x, w):
    a_1_1 = z;
    a_1_2 = z * w;
    a_2_1 = z * x;
    a_2_2 = z * x * y;

    a_1 = np.array([a_1_1,a_1_2]).T
    a_2 = np.array([a_2_1,a_2_2]).T
    res = k(a_1,a_2)

    return res

start=time.time()
[I_app_b_3_b_3, err] = nquad(func, [[0,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,1]])
end=time.time()

print(end-start)
```

Comment: Just to add I have now directly implemented tensor product Gauss-Legendre quadrature with 5 quadrature points and it  takes about 0.025 seconds to compute the same result as nquad - except its approx. 250 times faster. This is without using any fancy Python/Numpy/Cython code (because I don't know any yet), just for loops. I am even more interested to know why nquad performs so incredibly badly now that I see the speed up without even using any high performance code?

Comment: Have you played with the `opts`, the tolerances, etc?  If the problem isn't with the speed of your `func`, then there could be a problem with convergence.